# Formula to check dates with no operative being registered (Date formula excel)

Tags: excel, database, date, validation, excel-formula

Good morning,

We have a database which shows all days in which operations can be registered. We are trying to find which days haven’t had an operation being registered.

Therefore, we built a table that showed various columns:

- A first column [DÍAS LAB] where I have made a list of every working day of the year by filling - series (date) - weekday
- A second column [DÍAS BLOTTER], that used the formula “COUNTIFS” to count how many operations we had for each day (in the first column). In some cases, since no operations were registered in various days, the formula would return a “0” `=COUNTIFS(Data[Fecha_Completa];A2)`
- Finally, a third column [OPERACIONES] that, using the formula “IF”, found the cells where we had a 0 in the third column, and returned the working day where it belonged (where no operations were registered). For example: 12th of February 2022 `=IF(C2=0;A2;"-")`

| DÍAS LAB |
| --- |
| 10/03/2022 |
| 10/03/2022 |
| 11/03/2022 |
| 14/03/2022 |
| 15/03/2022 |
| 16/03/2022 |
| 17/03/2022 |
| 18/03/2022 |
| 21/03/2022 |
| 22/03/2022 |
| 23/03/2022 |
| 24/03/2022 |
| 25/03/2022 |
| 28/03/2022 |
| 29/03/2022 |
| 30/03/2022 |
| 31/03/2022 |
| 01/04/2022 |
| 04/04/2022 |
| 05/04/2022 |
| 06/04/2022 |

| DÍAS BLOTTER |
| --- |
| jueves, 10 de marzo de 2022 |
| viernes, 11 de marzo de 2022 |
| lunes, 14 de marzo de 2022 |
| martes, 15 de marzo de 2022 |
| miércoles, 16 de marzo de 2022 |
| jueves, 17 de marzo de 2022 |
| viernes, 18 de marzo de 2022 |
| lunes, 21 de marzo de 2022 |
| miércoles, 23 de marzo de 2022 |
| jueves, 24 de marzo de 2022 |
| viernes, 25 de marzo de 2022 |
| lunes, 28 de marzo de 2022 |
| miércoles, 30 de marzo de 2022 |
| jueves, 31 de marzo de 2022 |
| viernes, 1 de abril de 2022 |
| lunes, 4 de abril de 2022 |
| martes, 5 de abril de 2022 |
| miércoles, 6 de abril de 2022 |
| jueves, 7 de abril de 2022 |
| viernes, 8 de abril de 2022 |

| OPERACIONES |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 6 |
| 14 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 0 |
| 2 |
| 6 |
| 35 |
| 10 |
| 0 |
| 2 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 4 |
| 10 |

By doing all this, we were able to find which days had operations in them and how many operations were registered in each of those working days but most importantly, we were able to find and know which working days had no operations registered in them `=UNIQUE(D2:D213)`.

However, we wanted to go a step further and try to achieve the same results, but without the need of creating a table with 3+ columns; since it’s much more complex and uncomfortable.

It would be great if we could formulate all of this to compress the space and achieve the same results in maybe only one column.

Do you know any formulas and combinations that could help us?

Comment: It would be helpful to have sample data here

Comment: You can use the `LET`-construct to avoid the helper columns - but without seeing sample data it is hard to explain. Best would be if you add them with [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation).

Comment: Thank you for you comments @Ike They have been very helpful and I have made some modifications following your ideas and instructions. Thanks so much for the help!